# Why do lumber prices soar but cost of gypsum does not drop?

Tags: elasticity, commodities

The cost of lumber has increased 3 fold over the last year, whereas the cost of other building materials such as gypsum has hardly budged.

In North America, lumber is a dominant material used in the construction of homes: it is abundantly used in framing, sheathing, and finishing. Equal abundant is the used of gypsum in the form of gypsum wall boards (GWB) better kown as "drywall sheets".

At my local hardware store the price of a "2x4" (a typical and versatile piece of dimensional lumber)  has tripled over the last few months, whereas the price of a sheet of drywall (e.g. a "4x8ft) has hardly budged.

I would have thought that

- both prices rise as a result of a soaring demand for new building and renovations
  or
- lumber prices would rise as a result of lacking lumber supply, and the resultant lower or tempered volume of new builds would dampen the price of gypsum

Clearly this is not what has happened. **So what is the supply-demand relationship here?**

Chart: cost of lumber

[image]

Graphic table: cost of miscellaneous building materials

[image]